# Send more than one term to algolia search

Tags: algolia

I'm implementing algolia search in my site and i want to get a set of data matching any id's i send to the search, so i need to know how could i send more than one parameter to the search, so i can send a set of ids, something like this:

```
let client = algoliasearch(APP_ID, API_KEY),
    index = client.initIndex(INDEX_NAME);

let term=["3223212","2423434"];
    index.search(term, callback)
```

This is not working right now, have any idea? or even how could i achieve my goal using another algolia feautre like filtering for instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to retrieve objects by their `objectID`s (which you can manually set at creation time to match your database `id`s), you can simply use the [`getObjects` method](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-client/javascript/search#find-by-ids).

Extract from the documentation:

> You can also retrieve a set of objects:
>
> ```
> index.getObjects(['myObj1', 'myObj2'], function(err, content) {
>   console.log(content);
> });
> ```

---

If you're trying to list all the records that belong to a group with a specific id, you can [use a facet](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-client/javascript/parameters#filtering--faceting) that will contain this id and filter on it.

Inside your record:

```js
{
  "group_id": "3223212",
  // or
  "group_ids": ["3223212", "2423434"]
}
```

Inside your index settings:

```js
{
  attributesForFaceting: [
    'onlyFilter(group_id)'
  ]
}
```

At query time:

```js
let ids = ["3223212", "2423434"];
let filters = ids.map(id => `group_id:${id}`).join(' OR ');
index.search('', { filters: filters }, callback);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i just have one more question, how can i set the 'attributesForFaceting' setting? I'm reading the docs and it seems that is not possible to do that using javascript. Is it possible to do it inside dashboard?

Comment: You can indeed also directly set it in the Display tab of your index inside your Dahsboard. You can also use `onlyFilter` there, you'll have to type it as it's written in the answer.